# How can I copy a list of files but continue sequentially (so file 1 = file n+1, 2 = n+2 etc)?

Tags: bash

I need to copy a bunch of files I have so they remain sequential. The files have the same format: `file-0.D`, `file-10.D`, `file-20.D`, ... `file-990.D`. I want to have file-0 = file-1000, file-10 = file-1010 etc. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To increment the number in each filename by 1000 and leave the rest untouched, you can use regular expressions:

```
re='(.*-)([[:digit:]]+)(.*)'
for f in file*; do
    [[ $f =~ $re ]]
    echo mv "$f" "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}$(( ${BASH_REMATCH[2]} + 1000 ))${BASH_REMATCH[3]}"
done
```

If the result looks like what you want, you can remove the `echo`.

Alternatively, if you have the Perl `rename` tool, you could use

```
rename -n 's/\d+/$&+1000/e' file-*
```

and drop the `-n` once the substitutions look alright. Notice that this won't work with the `rename` tool from the util-linux project.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
for f in file*.D; do cp "$f" dir/file-$(( i++ + 1000 )).D; done
```

it iterates over the files matching the pattern and then copy them to another directory increasing the value of `i` and adding 1000.

Comment: Can you explain your code and why it solves the issue? *Code only* answers are often not that helpful.